# SwiftUI equivalent to textFieldShouldReturn

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Is there a SwiftUI equivalent for `textFieldShouldReturn`? I would like my app to run a command after I press the return/enter key in a TextField. macOS App

Comment: Which iOS are you targeting?

Comment: Sorry my bad, using macOS

Comment: Which version? SwiftUI is quite unstable and things have changed in Monterey compared to Big Sur and Catalina.

Comment: I am targeting macOS Big Sur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Big Sur, just use `TextField`'s `onCommit` closure. For later versions, check out [`onSubmit(of:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/onsubmit(of:_:)).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Text", text: $text) { isEditing in
            print("Textfield is editing: \(isEditing)") /// in case you want to update your UI
        } onCommit: {
            print("Return pressed") /// for your logic
        }
    }
}
```